# Does SmartGit have a way to do three way conflict resolution?

Tags: git, version-control, smartgit

Is it possible, in SmartGit, to perform a visual three way merge for conflict resolution?  I know that Git Extensions can do this, and I believe TortoiseGit can do this.

I thought this would be a commonly used, and important feature, but I can't figure out how to do it in SmartGit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SmartGit has a built-in Conflict Solver: invoke **Query|Conflict Solver** on *conflicting* file.

Comment: Amazed that I missed that, thanks.  I guess I was relying too heavily on the right-click context menu.

Comment: You can also double click a conflicted file to open the Conflict Solver.